# Is there an easy way to clear an ASP.NET form?

Tags: asp.net-2.0

is there an easy way to reset ALL text fields in an asp.net form - like the reset button for html controls?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794136/clear-all-fields-in-asp-net-form

Answer (score 7):

Depends on your definition of reset. A trivial way to do something like this could be a button with codebehind:

```
Response.Redirect(Request.Url.PathAndQuery, true);
```

Or a variation thereof.

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnReset" runat="server" Text="Reset" 
OnClientClick="this.form.reset();return false;" />
```

Comment: why you added return false at the end?

Comment: in order to prevent the default action of clicking the button and only run this portion of code that he wrote

Comment: This should be accepted as the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
<input type="reset" value="Clear" />
```

Comment: I'm surprised this answer was not given already. It would be more useful with a bit more detail; Explain that an ASP.NET form is really just an HTML form, and so putting that control inside the `<form>` element will work just as usual.

Comment: Seems to me the most elegant solution suggested here.

Answer (score 3):

Using javascript you can do:

```
document.forms[0].reset();
```

or

```
theForm.reset();  // at least with ASP.NET 2.0
```

As in

```
<input type='button' id='resetButton' value='Reset' onclick='theForm.reset();return false;' //>
```

Answer (score 1):

Some solutions are listed here:

[Clear a form in ASP.Net](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-42337.html)

> I was looking for the same solution in ASP.Net to clear my form on the click and I landed on this post. I looked at all the comments and replies. I decided to use the plain old input tag and created a HTML reset button .It worked like a charm, no postbacks, not javascripts. If there is any catch, I couldn't find it...

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
function resetForm() 
{ 
   var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
   for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) 
   { 
       if(input[i].type == 'text')
          input[i].value = "";
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to clear all controls in your form on a submit is:

```
form1.Controls.Clear()
```

Comment: form.controls.clear() will remove all controls from form, reset form is to clear control's values