# How to reset ASP.NET Form? aspnetForm.reset() causes Event Validation invalid postback error

Tags: asp.net, reset, eventvalidation

I need to reset an ASP.NET form.  I am trying to use document.aspnetForm.reset() but then whenever I try to do anything after that I get an event validation error.  How can I reset my form without upsetting ASP.NET's Event Validation?  I CANNOT turn off event validation.  Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274857/is-there-an-easy-way-to-clear-an-asp-net-form and many more.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to clear each form element manually.  If you have jQuery you could retrieve all `input[@type="text"]` and set their value to `""` and so on for other form elements...

Answer (score -1):

Add `return false;` to you javascript code. It will prevent postback.