# Clear all fields in ASP.net form

Tags: asp.net

Is there an easy way to reset all the fields in a form?

I have around 100 controls in my asp.net form and there are submit and reset buttons.

How do I make all values in the fields null when user hits reset button?

I have a lot of dropdown boxes, textboxes, checkboxes.

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680241/blank-out-a-form-with-jquery

Comment: @Claudio, the OP is asking how to reset all fields of a form in an ASP.NET application. Nothing is mentioned about jQuery and voting to close this answer as an exact duplicate seems wrong to me.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: maybe you're right. Assuming that everyone is using/ is willing to use jquery (even nowadays) could be too pretentious. Sorry but I can't revert my vote so far I know. BTW: I still thinking that input type reset may led to a confusion.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Loop through all of the controls on the page, and if the control is type TextBox, set the Text property to String.Empty

```
protected void ClearTextBoxes(Control p1)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in p1.Controls)
    {
        if(ctrl is TextBox)
        {
             TextBox t = ctrl as TextBox;

             if(t != null)
             {
                  t.Text = String.Empty;
             }
        }
        else
       {
           if (ctrl.Controls.Count > 0)
           {
               ClearTextBoxes(ctrl);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Then to call it in your click event like this:

```
 ClearTextBoxes(Page);
```

Answer (score 19):

Add this to the server-side handler of the cancel button:

```
Response.Redirect("~/mypage.aspx", false);
```

Comment: This would lose all viewstate data, which might not be desirable.

Comment: If we're clearing out all the fields, we obviously don't need to retain the ViewState in the first place... we're simply re-loading the page afresh which is the simplest way of doing this. He specified that all fields were being cleared :-)

Comment: May I ask why you call redirect with second parameter `true`? Wouldn't you rather use `false` to prevent an `AbortThreadException`? ([Relevant link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tmarq/2009/06/25/correct-use-of-system-web-httpresponse-redirect/).)

Answer (score 10):

Try adding an:

```
<input type="reset" value="Clear" />
```

to your form.

Comment: So far I know that would initialize forms field to the initial state. If the initial state for a texbox was "HELLO" It will reset to that value. I don't think it's what the user needs.

Answer (score 10):

You can make use of `OnClientClick` event. This will reset all all the control present on the form.  `OnClientClick="this.form.reset();return false;"`

See the Code :

```
<asp:Button ID="Reset_Button" runat="server" Text="Reset" 
    Width="81px" OnClientClick="this.form.reset();return false;" />
```

Comment: it's working before submitting the form only. when i submit the form and then if i click on reset, the form is not getting cleared.

Comment: OnClientClick is always called before server side code so what's that point to clear the form before submitting /?????

Comment: This worked for me, but how do I make it clear all forms on 1 page, I have a page that has 4 forms for some odd reason, but I want to clear all on a single click

Answer (score 5):

The best option from my side would be

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
```

Just add this code on the cancel or reset button of your asp.net control.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using asp.net formview object,   just use `myFormView.DataBind();` in your reset button click event.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you are using Angular.

Add this to your button on the cshtml page:

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel" id="cancel" ng-click="cancel();" />
```

And this to your .js file:

```
$scope.cancel = function () {
    if (!$('form').dirtyForms('isDirty')) {
        $('form').dirtyForms('setClean');
    }
    else {
        $('form').dirtyForms('isDirty', true);
    }
     var that = this;
    var method = that.getUrl('CONTROLLER', 'ACTION', 'id', 'querystring');
    window.location = method;
```