# Clearing all fields in an asp.net form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an `asp.net` `form`. In this `form`I want to clear all the data what I entered  in `textbox`,`dropdownlist` etc. So how can I do without going to each textbox and set the value.

like `TextBox1.Text="";` etc. How can i clear all values of a form ?

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794136/clear-all-fields-in-asp-net-form

Comment: What exactly is the problem with clearing each control separately ?

Comment: i need a simple thing Redirecting to the page is enough..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a reset button , on the client side :

```
<input type="reset" />
```

Another alternative is to redirect to the current url :

```
Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.RawUrl)
```

This technique will redirect the user to the current page, as if he just arrived.
However, this in only possible if your page is not built with some postback (since the viewstate will be reset).

At least, you can "walk" the entire control tree and clear values of controls of your choice, based for example on the type of the control.

Answer (score 21):

Either

Use this function

```
private void ClearInputs(ControlCollection ctrls)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in ctrls)
    {
        if (ctrl is TextBox)
            ((TextBox)ctrl).Text = string.Empty;
        else if (ctrl is DropDownList)
            ((DropDownList)ctrl).ClearSelection();

        ClearInputs(ctrl.Controls);
    }
}
```

and call it like

```
ClearInputs(Page.Controls);
```

or

Redirect to the same page

```
Response.Redirect(Request.Url.PathAndQuery, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can recurse through the control tree using the `Controls` property of the page and the child controls. For each control you can then reset it using code like

```
if (ctl is ITextControl)
    ((ITextControl)ctl).Text = "";
```

and variations on that theme for checkboxes etc.